# (vagrant & ssh) require password

Tags: ssh, vagrant

my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
config.vm.box_check_update = false
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
config.vm.synced_folder "./synced/", "/home/vagrant/"
config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
config.ssh.forward_agent = true

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
    vb.name = "test Ubuntu 14.04 box"
end
end
```

When I try execute

```
vagrant ssh
```

ssh requires password.

But Vagrant should use my local ssh key and do not require password.

Comment: Can you try removing `config.ssh.private_key_path` line?

Comment: I had tried and this does not help.

Comment: can you please paste the console output after you `vagrant up`

Comment: Might be worth having a look at this change in vagrant: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/4707 and see if adding 'config.ssh.insert_key = false' helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue. The problem is you're trying to synch into guest's home folder. I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599297/changing-vagrantfile-causes-vagrant-ssh-to-prompt-for-a-password?answertab=active#tab-top), please refer to that post for more info. You need to change your synch paths.

Instead of

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./synced/", "/home/vagrant/"
```

do

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./synced/", "/home/vagrant/mySyncFolder"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the line like below in your `~/.ssh/config` ?

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
```

In my case, after removing this line, `vagrant ssh` stopped asking me for password.